# How to deal with timezone to compute lag

Tags: java, angular, typescript

I'm trying to compute the lag in miliseconds between my client (from France) and my server (from Germany).

Client side (Angular Typescript) :

```
this.http.getDate().subscribe(response => {
               if (response.type === HttpEventType.Sent) {

           const dateSent = new Date();
            const dateOffset = dateSent.getTimezoneOffset();
            const timeSent = dateSent.getTime() + dateOffset;
            console.log(timeSent);

    } else if (response instanceof HttpResponse) {


          const dateReceived = new Date(response.body.dateReceived);
          const timeReceived = dateReceived.getTime();
          console.log(timeReceived);
        }
      });
```

Server side (Java) :

```
return new Date();
```

timeSent = 1559221214039 and timeReceived = 1559221212914

Why the difference between them is -1125‬ miliseconds ? With the developer tool of firefox, the network says, it tooks 200ms.

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

> Javascript date getTimezoneOffset() method returns the time-zone offset
>   in minutes for the current locale. The time-zone offset is the minutes
>   in difference, the Greenwich Mean Time (GMT) is relative to your local
>   time.
>
> For example, if your time zone is GMT+10, -600 will be returned.
>   Daylight savings time prevents this value from being a constant.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/date_gettimezoneoffset.htm

you are multiplying by 60*1000

Comment: That's what I'm already doing. I have improved the content of my question

Comment: Hi, insted of sending back and forth the "DATE" can you "simply" save the ms when you send and the ms when you recieve?

`if (response.type === HttpEventType.Sent) {
          this.dateSent = new Date();

    } else if (response instanceof HttpResponse) {
          console.log(this.dateSend - new Date());
        }
      });`

Comment: Lag (Latency) is the time between the time the client packet is sent and the time the packet is received at the server. So I guess no...